# Solr Suggester returns 0 results when context language is en-AU

Tags: solr, sitecore, autosuggest, search-suggestion

I have a **list of product pages** for one of my Australia sites where the content is in 2 language versions:

- EN
- en-AU

I have a search suggestion box where I am trying to populate few of the title fields through a computed field named as **autosuggestiontitle_sm**

Here's my suggester component defined in solrconfig.xml:

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
        <lst name="suggester">
            <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
            <str name="lookupImpl">BlendedInfixLookupFactory</str>
            <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
            <str name="field">**autosuggestiontitle_sm**</str>         
            <str name="contextField">**_contextLanguage**</str>
            <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">**text_suggester**</str>
            <str name="buildOnStartup">true</str>
        </lst>
</searchComponent>
<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy" >
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="suggest">true</str>
            <str name="suggest.dictionary">mySuggester</str>
            <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
        </lst>
        <arr name="components">
            <str>suggest</str>
        </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Since my suggestAnalyzerFieldType is a custom field, I have included the below entries in managed-schema file as below:

```
<fieldType **name="text_suggester"** class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

And have added the 2 custom fields by defining the type as text_suggester:

```
<field name="autosuggestiontitle_sm" type="text_suggester" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="_contextLanguage" type="text_suggester" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Since _language is a string type I have defined a custom field name as _contextLanguage of type text_suggester so added the below **copyField **entry:

Then, I did restart my solr server and re-indexed my custom index pertaining to my website context.
Now my search term is "fit".

Scenario 1 Query: https://localhost:8983/solr/custom_master_index/suggest?q=fit
Result is as expected which is picking 7 results where "fit" terms appears in title text from both EN and en-AU versions
[image]

Scenario 2 Query: https://localhost:8983/solr/custom_master_index/suggest?q=fit&suggest=true&suggest.cfq=en
Result is as expected which is picking 2 results where "fit" terms appears in title text from EN content.
[image]

But the issue is that when I query with en-AU which is my current context language of my Australia site, the result is either 0 or at time I see the EN results.
**(Issue)Scenario 3 Query**: https://localhost:8983/solr/custom_master_index/suggest?q=fit&suggest=true&suggest.cfq=en-AU
Note: I have tried to run the query with different values like suggest.cfq=en-au, suggest.cfq=au (nothing helped)
[image]

Can someone help me understand what is being missed so that en-AU contextField is not querying the right values.

Thanks in advance!